# How to write a function in javascript to match two words

Tags: javascript, html, string, function, match

I am new in coding. I was working on a typing website which match the word in text field to the word shown in the website. How to write the function in Javascript. Here is what I have tried.

```js
let displayWord = document.getElementById('word').innerHTML
let displayMessage = document.getElementById('message')
let inpWord = document.getElementById('input').value

function matchWords() {
    if(displayWord === inpWord){
        console.log('words matching')
    }   
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

</head>
<body class="bg-secondary text-white">
    <header class="text-center p-2 bg-dark ">
        <h1>Typing test</h1>
    </header>
    
   <div class="container text-center">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
                <p class="p-4">Type The Given Text</p>
                <h2 class="word pb-4" id="word">Hello</h2>
                <input class="form-control form-control-lg" type="text" name="" id="input">
                <h4 id="message" class="p-4"></h4>
            </div>
        </div>
   </div>
  
    
<script src="script.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.9.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-IQsoLXl5PILFhosVNubq5LC7Qb9DXgDA9i+tQ8Zj3iwWAwPtgFTxbJ8NT4GN1R8p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-cVKIPhGWiC2Al4u+LWgxfKTRIcfu0JTxR+EQDz/bgldoEyl4H0zUF0QKbrJ0EcQF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You want to match words after each key down or just one time?

Comment: Couple of things,.. 1: matchWords is never called anywhere, you might want to attach the input event to the input.  2. `innerText` and not `innerHTML` might be a better option for comparing.  Also the `.innerText` need checking inside your function, otherwise it's value is always going to be what it was when the page was rendered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your script looks good by far, you just need to set an event handler to your input to trigger your function when user types in it.

below your code refactored with some suggestions:

1. use const instead of let when variable is not going to change.
2. is it better to store the HTML element that way you'll be able to do more with it.

in this case I use the input element to change its outline color and also change the message

```
const word = document.getElementById('word')
const message = document.getElementById('message')
const inputText = document.getElementById('input')

function matchWords() {
    if(word.innerHTML === inputText.value){
      message.innerHTML = "It does match!"
      inputText.style.outline = "1px solid green"
    } else {
      message.innerHTML = "It does not match!"
      inputText.style.outline = "1px solid red"
    }
}

inputText.onkeyup = () => matchWords()
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is, that you grab the value when the document is loaded but at this point the value is empty.

If you change your code to this it should be updating the h4 field while you type.

```js
let displayWord = document.getElementById("word").innerHTML;
let displayMessage = document.getElementById("message");
let inpWord = document.getElementById("input");

function matchWords() {
  if (displayWord === inpWord.value) {
    displayMessage.innerText = "words matching";
  }
}

input.addEventListener("keyup", matchWords);
```